# Consuming web service with WSCF, Unicode characters deserializing to '??'

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, unicode, wscf

We use WSCF (Web Services Contract First) to create client proxies to consume another web service that we own.  The web service is returning "special" characters such as ® in some of the fields.  We are seeing these characters as "??" (it is actually two question mark characters, not a rendering issue) when the web service response is deserialized to an object.  This deserialization seems to be done under the hood with WSCF.

In a conventional "web reference" - I've found a few posts on the net that say you can simply add this method to your Reference.vb file to alleviate this problem.

```
    Protected Overrides Function GetWebResponse(request As System.Net.WebRequest) As System.Net.WebResponse
        Dim res As System.Net.WebResponse = MyBase.GetWebResponse(request)
        res.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text-xml; charset=UTF-8")
        Return res
    End Function
```

The proxy class that WSCF generates with method stubs inherits from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol so I am able to put this same method in there.  I had high hopes that this would resolve our problem, but in debugging through the web service call, the GetWebResponse function is never called.

The "closest" I can get to getting the response in code is as follows (this is generated code).  Arg is the response and the deserialization has already botched the "special" characters.

```
    Private Sub Onv2_0OperationCompleted(ByVal arg As Object)
        If (Not (Me.v2_0CompletedEvent) Is Nothing) Then
            Dim invokeArgs As System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs = CType(arg, System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)
            RaiseEvent v2_0Completed(Me, New v2_0CompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Short of ripping out WSCF (which would be a pretty huge effort for this application) - does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?

I've verified the web service we're consuming is returning the characters correctly, using Fiddler. I also just created a service reference to it in a test harness and it works fine. If I have to go back to management and say we need to update our web references to be modern service references, so be it - but I'm hoping we don't have to do that.

Comment: Web references aren't "conventional" - they're obsolete. Why not simply try "Add Service Reference" - just to see what happens in this one case.

Comment: [WSCF](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/wscf) latest version ***0.7*** is from ***2007***. 'nuff said.

Comment: I hear ya!  But we're in a situation here where "it is what it is" - if I could get a project funded to rip the whole app apart and redesign it to modern standards, that would be great but I'm sure you know how that goes.

Comment: And to your point, the upstream web service does pull the Unicode values out of another service just fine, using a Service Ref.  This piece is just the old man on the block.  Unicode characters were pretty well established in 2007, it seems like this shouldn't be a stretch.

Comment: Like I said: create a test application to call this one service with "Add Service Reference" - just to see if it works.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the original post, but I've verified the web service we're consuming is returning the characters correctly, using Fiddler.  I also just created a service reference to it in a test harness and it works fine.  If I have to go back to management and say we need to update our web references, so be it - but I'm hoping we don't have to do that.

Comment: Please update your question with that last information. It's important that a Service Reference returns the data correctly, but that WSCF does not. Possibly due to being from 2007 and still not yet verson 1.